# Gemfile: A better way to conditionally declare local or remote gems for multiple developers

Tags: bundler

Our group has several people, any number of which may be working on any combination of gems. Currently, our Gemfile has stuff like this:

```
gem 'awesome-gem', :git => 'git@github.com:somebody/awesome-gem.git'
# gem 'awesome-gem', :path => '/Users/developer-A/workspace/awesome-gem'

# gem 'rad-gem', :git => 'git@github.com:somebody/rad-gem.git', :branch => 'release'
gem 'rad-gem', :path => '/some/path/specific-to/developer-B/rad-gem'
```

So developer-A was working on awesome-gem locally, and when they finished up, they just replaced their :path the gem's :git location and committed both to version control. developer-B and C do the same thing for rad-gem, each has a different :path in their locally modified Gemfile and if the Gemfile every has real changes, they have to undo their local :path setup, commit, undo to point back to their local version of rad-gem, etc.

This is both a pain and ugly, so I tried to come up with a better solution but the best I could come up with is something like this:

```
if ENV['RADGEM_PATH']
  gem 'rad-gem', :path => ENV['RADGEM_PATH']
else
  gem 'rad-gem', :git => 'git@github.com:somebody/rad-gem.git', :branch => 'release'
end
```

This allows developer-B and C to set their own rad-gem path while removing much of the pain mentioned above. however, it is still ugly and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, possibly using groups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update (current)**

A recent update to bunder now provides [local git repos](http://bundler.io/v1.2/man/bundle-config.1.html#LOCAL-GIT-REPOS). This is the current way of solving this problem. Thank you sekrett

**Update (outdated)**

If you have Bundler >= 1.2, there is now a [better way to do this](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/man/bundle-config.1.html#LOCAL-GIT-REPOS). For example,

```
bundle config local.blog ~/Work/gems/blog
```

**original answer (outdated)**

A friend of mine on the rspec core team showed me [the approach they used in the rspec-core Gemfile](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Gemfile#L6-13), so I guess I'll use that.

Comment: URL for documentation is now http://gembundler.com/v1.2/man/bundle-config.1.html#LOCAL-GIT-REPOS

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you also have a dynamic Gemfile that in development uses a hidden file (.my_local_gems) for the location of gems on that user's machine? Or you could even use some environment variable for a variable like GEMS_DEVEL_HOME?

Either way, it would force everyone to keep all of their local gems up to date and in production or staging, the normal Gemfile would take effect.

Remember, the Gemfile is just ruby so you can include all kinds of code in there, not just bundler-specific idioms.